# x-power-by display in response header

Tags: java, security, jboss

As per the security of web application x-power-by should set to empty when it displays in response header..
In our application we did this by implementing a filter.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
    // App specific logic...
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By","");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
 httpResponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By"," ");
}
```

It is showing blank value in response header for x-power-by when hitting the URL, That's well and good but in our application when we hit the URL with query string appended with the URL then for the first request it shows :

```
x-power-by= JSF1.2
```

We have also commented out the below portion of x-power-by in web.xml  as our application use jboss 5.0.1.

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CommonHeadersFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter</filter-class>
         <!--
      <init-param>
         <param-name>X-Powered-By</param-name>
         <param-value>Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1</param-value>
      </init-param>
      -->
   </filter>
```

But doing all the two things mention above I am getting x-power-by displayed in the response header when I hit the URL with query string appended for the 1st time.

URL like:
https://example.com?html="abcd",p_ab="shdhsgdhs"

Don't know how to resolve it,any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: does your control hitting doFilter when you use URL with parameter?

Comment: yes. Filter is calling when I hit the URL.

Comment: Is it pre-processing filter or post processing filter? My guess is first request going to different method than what you are assuming. I would suggest investigating that part.

Comment: It is post processing filter.I have also commented in web.xml x-power-by part in jboss 5.0.1..If it is going to different method then also it should display as blank..

Comment: only in Fiddler I am able to trace the issues. In IE by pressing F12 and going to network part I am not able to trace that.

Comment: Interesting, I have no other suggestions except restart everything/clear cache and see. Based on jboss documentation, web.xml comment should suppress that header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108315/discussion-between-arindam-kotal-and-nambari).

Comment: Thanks Nambari..It is working now..

Comment: Good. Glad it worked. I added it as answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add following entry to your application `web.xml`.

```
<context-param> 
<param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name> 
<param-value>false</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

2) I don't think you need any filter to overwrite this header (based on jboss documentation).